# JVCL Component Documentation

Tags: delphi, jvcl

I've just installed the JCL and JVCL libraries, mostly because they contain components replacing the old rxLib components and I'm upgrading an old project that made heavy use of those components.

I now find myself with numerous new tabs in my Delphi 2010 IDE, but no hint (beyond the component names) of what these components do.  How does TJvEdit differ from TEdit?  What is TJvSpecialImage?

Examination of the JVCL help directory and a google search has not been able to find even so much as a list of components included in the library.  Does anyone know if such a document exists?

**Edit, Follow-Up Question:**

Now that Lars showed me where to download the help files from, I can't get them installed in the Delphi help system.  Obviously, I'm supposed to use the h2reg utility supplied with Delphi to apply the files (with the JVCL333_h2reg.ini file to drive the process, I assume), but the only hints I can find on doing this stress the danger of corrupting the help system by doing it incorrectly.

(Note: I also have D2007 installed on this machine, but only want to install the help file in D2010).

Comment: You might also want to take a look at the "Mega Demo" that shows how many of the visual components work: [http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/files/JVCL%20Demos/JVCL%203.00%20Mega%20Demo/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/files/JVCL%20Demos/JVCL%203.00%20Mega%20Demo/)

Comment: Thanks.  I did see that and played around with it, but it didn't compile immediately under D2010 (it contains a call to WinExec that expected PAnsiChar).  I'll take another look.

Comment: You might want to post your follow up question as a seperate stackoverflow question

Comment: As lars said, so it should be; One Question Per Question. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Didn't your installation come with Help? Well, you can find it here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/files/JVCL%20Help%20Files/ or use the online help at http://help.delphi-jedi.org/

You can find a list of the available types on http://help.delphi-jedi.org/browse.php?Id=12&types=1. A similar list is included in the offline help. Not every part seems to be documented yet. That might be the price to pay for using open source.

> **TJvEdit** 
> Supports extended
>   features such as alignment, password
>   protection, custom caret and disabling
>   clipboard commands.
>
> TJvEdit implements the
>   generic behavior introduced in
>   TJvCustomEdit:
>  
>  * Use
>   Alignment to align the text in the
>   edit box.
>  * Use MaxPixel to limit
>   the maximum text size in pixels.
>  *
>   Use DisabledColor and
>   DisabledTextColor to specify a
>   disabled color and text color.
>  *
>   Use ClipboardCommands to disable
>   specific clipboard commands.
>  * Use
>   Caret to provide a custom caret
>   shape.
>
> **TJvSpecialImage** 
> Supports
>   extended features such as fade in,
>   fade out and image flipping.
>
> TJvSpecialImage is an
>   image that can be used to create
>   special effects.
>  
>  For example,
>   you can use the methods FadeIn, and
>   FadeOut to let an image slowly appear
>   and disappear on the form. The same
>   effect can be accomplished by using
>   the property Brightness, which sets
>   the brightness of the image. Set
>   Stretch to True to reduce
>   flickering.
>  
>  Use the Flipped
>   and Mirrored to flip the image
>   vertically or horizontally. Use
>   Inverted to invert the image.
>  
>   Call Reset to restore the image to its
>   original state.

Comment: Thank you.  No, my installation does not appear to have included the help files, although it did create and populate a help directory with HTML files covering installation and migration issues.  Perhaps installing help was an option I overlooked during the installation process?

Comment: I'm sorry, my selection of particular components to ask about was only rhetorical — to show that I couldn't guess the function from the name.

Answer (score 0):

It is very good to contribute a bug report at http://issuetracker.delphi-jedi.org/my_view_page.php about the Mega Demo not working (compile failed) in delphi 2010.